# How to align text in SharePoint List

Tags: list

I'm trying to align the text in the project column to the first row in Project description in SharePoint list. Can you please help?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "display": "table",
    "width": "100%"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "style": {
        "display": "table-cell",
        "vertical-align": "top"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

> **Note**, you can set the "vertical-align": "10px" as per needs!